# how to check item in a list contains in python

Tags: python, string, list, special-characters

I have 2 lists,

```
my_list = ['on@3','one',"$", "lo#"]
spl = ["@","$"]
```

I am trying to get the items in 'my_list' which contains any of the items in spl.

I tried

```
out_list = [item for item in my_list if item.contains("!".join(spl))]
```

but this gives error.

My expected output is

```
out_list = ["on@3","$"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No such method as `item.contains`. There's `item.__contains__`, but you don't need to call that directly.

You want to check if *any* of the items in `spl` is contained in the item, use the builtin **`any`**:

```
lst = [item for item in my_list if any(x in item for x in spl)]
# ...                           if any(item.__contains__(x) for x in spl)]
print(lst)
# ['on@3', '$']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
result = [item for item in my_list for s in spl if s in item]
```

And more human readable form:

```
result = []

for item in my_list:
    for s in spl:
        if s in item:
            result.append(item)
```

Comment: The nested loop isn't correct. If an item contains more than one of those characters, it gets duplicated.  Try with `my_list=['on@3$', 'one', "$", "lo#"]`

Comment: ok ill try with the value you mentioned, but this solution is taking less time

Comment: yes,I am getting the same value two time, I think of applying `list(set(result))` after getting the result for this solution, cos still this takes less time, what do you say? @MosesKoledoye

Comment: @CHANDRAMURUGAN You lose the initial ordering of your list once you call `set` on it. And the round-trip from list to set, then set to list is unnecessary and will slow down your code when the data set increases. Lastly, if your list contained an *unhashable* item, `set(result)` won't work.

Comment: ya I know but 

     `%timeit out_list = [item for item in my_list if any(x in item for x in spl)]  best of 3: 3.26 µs per loop`

     `% timeit result = [item for item in my_list for s in spl if s in item] best of 3: 920 ns per loop` +`timeit list(set(result))   3: 585 ns per loop`  is still lesser than 3.26µs

Comment: If `my_list` contained a list e.g. `my_list = ['on@3', ['o', 'n', 'e'], "$", "lo#"]`, you can't do `set(my_list)` because the inner list is unhashable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @MosesKoledoye, but in my case it will remain a single dimension list.